# biblatex autocite superscript is pushed out into the page margin

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, superscripts

I am currently writing a tex document, for which I used the superscript autocite style like so:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    autocite = superscript,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{projektarbeit.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

Viele solcher Plattformen wurden mithilfe von C/C++ oder Java entwickelt\autocite{abar2017}, was zum einen erfordert, dass diese Plattformen und ihre Abhängigkeiten installiert werden müssen, und zum anderen, dass die Agenten mit dieser oder einer kompatiblen Sprache erstellt werden.

\end{document}
```

With this bib file:

```
@article{abar2017,
    shorthand = {aba17},
    title = "Agent Based Modelling and Simulation tools: A review of the state-of-art software",
    author = "Abar, Sameera and Theodoropoulos, Georgios K and Lemarinier, Pierre and O'Hare, Gregory M P",
    journal = "Comput. Sci. Rev.",
    volume = 24,
    pages = "13--33",
    year = 2017,
    language = "en"
}
```

Which results in a PDF looking like this:

[image: PDF output]

It is hard to see, but the reference `aba17` is pushed out of the paragraph bounds.
Is there any way to suggest latex to break the line / word if the reference is making the line too long and move the reference to the next line?

Comment: If you can't hyphenate `entwickelt` or change the width of the line, then perhaps you can re-write the sentence so the autocite is not at the end of a line?

Comment: @Thruston yeah, this is what I did in the end. The question was more how to avoid this generally, since (as I undestand it) the main prupose of LaTeX is to layout text, so it fits the requirements, which include that superscript is part of the line length.

Comment: You can't avoid the problem *in general*.  The paragraph breaking algorithm is very clever but it is not magic.  Sometimes is just has to choose the least worst of several bad options.  You can reduce the chance of bad breaks by (a) allowing `\sloppy` paragraph settings, (b) making sure you have the right hyphenation set for your language, (c) setting the text ragged right (d) making the lines longer, or (e) making the *paragraph* longer.    Or using a more compact reference scheme :-)  Or indeed, rewriting-to-avoid-the-problem.

Comment: @Thruston Ok, thank you. Well it alwyas feels like, that the superscript is handled like an edge case. LaTeX does not seem to hyphenate any words with a superscript attached anymore and it does not count it towords the line length, like it does with all the other text items. This seems more like a bug than anything else.